# Does Julmar Wrapper Atapi Support Tapi 3.X

Tags: .net, winapi, wrapper, telephony, tapi

I am very novice in the field of telephony application programming.Basically i am a .NET developer.So i tried to find out a good wrapper for Microsoft's Tapi in C# using .Net platform and got Julmar's ATAPI.Now my Question...

Does Julmar's Atapi supports Tapi 3.X ? or it just Supports Tapi 2.X ?.

Also what features i will miss if it supports Tapi 2.X only.Also Is there a way by which i can Manage to use microsoft's Tapi 3.X from Julmar's Atapi in-case it does not support Tapi 3.X.

Answer (score 0):

late to the party on this one but in case anyone else stumbles across this - you need the ITAPI codebase from julmar to work with TAPI 3.x which is available here http://itapi3.codeplex.com/